# Incorporating PYQT GUI significantly increases loop time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been working on converting a program which took a CSV file as inputs for a modelling application that iterated over several thousant timesteps and and did calculations on each. In this format, the program took 1-2min max to complete. During the calculation I utilized a simple TKinter progress bar to indicate simulation progress.

With the completed UI using PyQT5, the calculation time slows down significantly. It now takes 30+ minutes to calculate.

Things I have tried:

QT threading: I pushed the calculation to a separate worker thread as outline here: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/

```
class Simulator(QObject):
    def __init__(self,inputs):
        super(Simulator, self).__init__()
        self.inputs = inputs

    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run_task(self):
        print(self.inputs)
        simEVs(self.inputs)
        self.finished.emit()
```

Hiding QWidgets & Blocking signals: for another project I found that updating a QTable widget, slowed down the program due to a multitude of signals being sent, so blocking signals for the widget increased performance there. Here I tried blocking signals and hiding all child elements of my UI during the simulation to no effect.

```
def sleep_ui(self):
    children = self.findChildren(QWidget)
    for child in children:  #ignore the double indent here
            child.blockSignals(True)
            child.setUpdatesEnabled(False)
            child.hide()
def wake_ui(self):
    children = self.findChildren(QWidget)
    for child in children:
        child.blockSignals(True)
        child.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        child.show()
```

In other code implementations, I've deleted the ui window and recreated it once the calculation has completed, but I'm trying to avoid that here.

here is an example of what I am talking about:

longsim() takes 0.0029883 secs with the UI and 0.0009970 secs without, an almost 300% increase in computation time.

longsim.py:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import time
pg.mkQApp()


def longsim():
    t = time.time()
    # do stuff
    tmax = 365*24*4
    timev = np.linspace(0,tmax)

    for i in timev:
        for i in timev: # an example loop with some placeholder calculations
            output = i*100

    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(elapsed)
```

stackexchange.py:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import matplotlib

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

from longloop import longsim
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

pg.mkQApp()

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
uiFile = os.path.join(path, 'Example.ui')
WindowTemplate, TemplateBaseClass = pg.Qt.loadUiType(uiFile)


class MainWindow(TemplateBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        TemplateBaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('window')

        # Create the main window
        self.ui = WindowTemplate()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.show()

    def clicked(self):
        longsim()

win = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

here is the UI file:
example.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>440</y>
     <width>621</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>248</x>
     <y>254</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>316</x>
     <y>260</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>286</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Comment: please provide a [MrE]

Comment: added examples at the bottom of my initial post

Comment: Why do you want that code to be faster than 0.0029883? If you are looking for speed then a GUI is not the best option since it will only be able to visualize changes of 30Hz

Comment: this was just an example calculation, the actual loop takes around 2-3 minutes to calculate without the GUI

Comment: Just as a point of reference, I ran your example three times in a row.  I got 0.002, 0.003, and 0.001.  You can't trust timing loops that short.  All it takes is one context change and your numbers are screwed.

Comment: 1) When does it increment in your real example ?, 2) If it takes a long time then run it in a child thread, 3) why do you import matplotlib and pyqtgraph in longloopsi longsim only use numpy? In stackexchange you import unnecessarily to matplotlib

Comment: If you're trying to DO stuff in your UI, that is certainly going to slow things down.  Remember that Python is burdened with the global interpreter lock: only one thread at a time can actually be running Python code.  If it's handling an event, your computation thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions, As is usually the case for things like this the bug was elsewhere. After fixing a value that should have been a percentage (0-1 instead of 0-100) the loop runs as it should. no issues with increased loop times as of yet.